# Oracle SQL: How to filter out rows based on different row values

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I want to filter my data, based on the following condtion

- For an ID, if a part appears twice or more than twice under the specific Types `A` and `B`, then I want to filter the data on that.

`data`

```
| ID  | TYPE | PART |
|-----|------|------|
| 101 | A    | 10   |
| 101 | B    | 10   |
| 101 | B    | 10   |
| 101 | B    | 20   |
| 101 | C    | 30   |
| 102 | A    | 10   |
| 102 | B    | 25   |
| 103 | A    | 25   |
| 103 | B    | 25   |
```

`output`

```
| ID  | Type | Part |
|-----|------|------|
| 101 | A    | 10   |
| 101 | B    | 10   |
| 101 | B    | 10   |
| 103 | A    | 25   |
| 103 | B    | 25   |
```

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT 101 id, 'A' type, 10 part FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 101 id, 'B' type, 10 part FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 101 id, 'B' type, 10 part FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 101 id, 'B' type, 20 part FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 101 id, 'C' type, 30 part FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 102 id, 'A' type, 10 part FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 102 id, 'B' type, 25 part FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 103 id, 'A' type, 25 part FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 103 id, 'B' type, 25 part FROM dual
)
SELECT * FROM data;
```

`another solution`

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT 101 id, 'A' type, 10 part FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 101 id, 'B' type, 10 part FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 101 id, 'B' type, 10 part FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 101 id, 'B' type, 20 part FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 101 id, 'C' type, 30 part FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 102 id, 'A' type, 10 part FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 102 id, 'B' type, 25 part FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 103 id, 'A' type, 25 part FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 103 id, 'B' type, 25 part FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 104 id, 'C' type, 30 part FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 104 id, 'D' type, 30 part FROM dual
), data2 AS (
    SELECT data.*, COUNT(DISTINCT type) OVER (PARTITION BY id, part) cnt
    FROM data
    WHERE type IN ('A','B')
)
SELECT id, type, part
FROM data2
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

Comment: Part 25 with ID 103 does not meet your request. It appears only twice, not more than twice. That should not be in your desired output per your description.

Comment: Apologies. I have updated it to `twice or more than twice`.

Comment: Have you tried using GROUP BY with HAVING clause?

Comment: @Shantanu your WITH clause sample data is wrong ... you have a final record of id = 104 .. I suspect it should be 103 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:
(I fixed the 104/103 record here, assuming to match your initial data)

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT 101 id, 'A' type, 10 part FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 101 id, 'B' type, 10 part FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 101 id, 'B' type, 10 part FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 101 id, 'B' type, 20 part FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 101 id, 'C' type, 30 part FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 102 id, 'A' type, 10 part FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 102 id, 'B' type, 25 part FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 103 id, 'A' type, 25 part FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 103 id, 'B' type, 25 part FROM dual
   ),
   w_cnt as
      ( SELECT id, part, count(*)
         FROM data
         group by id, part
         having count(*) > 1
       )
select *
from data   d,
     w_cnt   w
where d.id = w.id
  and d.part = w.part
/

        ID T       PART         ID       PART   COUNT(*)
---------- - ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       103 B         25        103         25          2
       103 A         25        103         25          2
       101 B         10        101         10          3
       101 B         10        101         10          3
       101 A         10        101         10          3

5 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 1):

That should do the trick:

```
select *
from data d
right join (
  select id, part
      from data
  group by id, part
    having count(part)>=2
) s on s.id = d.id and s.part = d.part
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it seems to be not matching with the expected output.

Comment: But your outcome contradicts your question. Id 102 occurs twice => should occur in the output. Or let's put it different: why is 102 not in the output?

Comment: So, 101 has the Part 10, appearing across the required two types 'A' and 'B'. The part is appearing twice or more than twice (as corrected). 102 has the requested types 'A' and 'B', but the part are different 10 and 25. 103 has the part appearing twice, across type 'A' and 'B', hence it is not filtered out.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it - fixed the query

Answer (score 1):

Just for variety, as there are often many ways to solve a single problem ..
here's a solution using analytics. (I'm not suggesting that this performs better or worse than the others . for that, please test/verify and benchmark ;) )

But it does give an alternative option.

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT 101 id, 'A' type, 10 part FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 101 id, 'B' type, 10 part FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 101 id, 'B' type, 10 part FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 101 id, 'B' type, 20 part FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 101 id, 'C' type, 30 part FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 102 id, 'A' type, 10 part FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 102 id, 'B' type, 25 part FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 103 id, 'A' type, 25 part FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 103 id, 'B' type, 25 part FROM dual
   ),
   sub as (
      Select id, type, part,
             count(*) over (partition by id, part) c
      from data
   )
Select id, type, part
from sub
where c > 1
/

        ID T       PART
---------- - ----------
       101 A         10
       101 B         10
       101 B         10
       103 A         25
       103 B         25

5 rows selected.
```